# Big Rubber Tire sound 

Tags: sfx, wheeled, vehicles

Hey guys. Any ideas for a rubber tire rolling sound that does NOT have a motor attached to it? I'm designing some of these rolling guys, and i'm going to use rubber on all of them, but i can't get anything without an engine running. I tried to record just my back tire while my wife was slowly driving my car (they're not moving too fast), and i just don't know if i can make this work for what I need. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Putting the car in neutral on an incline and letting it roll downhill (with someone in the driver's seat of course) can also work for this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Wheel barrows usually have rubber tires on them. Throw some in **soft** weight that won't bounce (canvas sand bags can be pretty good), rig up your mic to the wheel barrow so you don't have to have someone chasing it, and push that sucker around.

The two wheel variants might be more stable and give you better control with less handling noise.

Comment: Run a separate take after you let some air out of the tire(s) also.

Comment: @Steve Urban - great point...gotta have some variation!

Comment: That's a sweet idea, i have really good wheelbarrow for this i think.

Comment: wheelbarrows are the One Ring of sound design

Comment: I had the perfect barrow for it. Two big chunky rubber tires. I didn't let the air out, as I was already freezing my balls off and i was wearing only socks on my feet because any shoes gave too much added noise. Thanks guys!

Answer (score 1):

wheelchairs and golf club caddie cars are great.